# Custom URL column in Document library

Tags: 2013, document-library, calculated-column, folder

In document library are several folders and documents.
**Name** column is linked to it's document. I created custom site pages for some of those folders and for all other folders I don't custom site page.
I have additional column let's say **URLText** (see image), where I store that custom page url.

What I want to do is to create additional column **Link**, that should check whether column **URLText** is empty or not. If empty copy link to folder from column **Name** and if not empty copy link from **URLText** column.

Thinking of creating WF in SPD2013, but is there faster/smarter/easier solution?

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with SPD workflow. Bellow is print-screen of a workflow.[image]

So I created additional two columns, beside **FolderURLText**. **FolderURLLink** and **Document Name**.
1st two columns are single line of text and **Document Name** is calculated column,

```
Document Name ="<a href='"&FolderURLLink&"'>"&Title&"</a>"
```

I didn't have to have this column, as FolderURLLink would do the job but I wanted to be more user friendly so I hid URL and put **Title** label instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calculated column, but you can't get the link in Name directly. You'll have to generate it in your calculated column using the same parameters (i.e. ID) that SharePoint uses to generate it.